# www IIS rewrite not respecting localhost

Tags: mod-rewrite, localhost, iis-express

I googled this to death and read all the entries on StackOverflow with no luck. The following rewrite rule is not being respected in my local development environment.

```
  <rule name="WWW-Rewrite" enabled="true"  stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.(.*)$" />
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="ft-ue-firstsav-com" />
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^localhost(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^127\.0\.0\.1(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
```

To fix this I put in a slow cheetah transform flipping the enabled attribute from true to false in Debug mode. While this works I want the actual rule to work.

Any suggestons?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules enable FRT to debug.

Comment: In all my searching I did not find this. Thanks for the pointer. If this helps I will update with the answer.

Comment: I should have also mentioned I am using Win 10 with IIS Express.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from using FRT. Either you edit the config file directly, or use a tool like Jexus Manager, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/